# State and Interaction based testing using jMockIt

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocks

I am new to jMockIt and so wanted to learn it. I thought of implementing a synonym servlet kata. The servlet takes a word as input and returns the synoyms of the words as a comma seperated string. The objective of the kata that I implemented was:

1. Learning jMockIt stubbing and mocking features.
2. Choosing between stubbing and mocking based on the situation.
3. Implementing readable, maintainable and trustworthy unit tests.

I request code reviewers to provide feedback in above mentioned areas. I am open to receive feedback about the servlet code as well. The code is below:

```
class SynonymServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public SynonymServlet(RecentCache cache, SynonymProvider provider) {
        this.cache = cache;
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        //input processing
        String word = getInputWordFromURL(request.getRequestURI());

        //cache management
        List<String> synonyms = cache.get(word);
        if (synonyms == null) {
            synonyms = provider.getSynonyms(word);
            cache.put(word, synonyms);
        }

        //response creation
        String responseString = StringUtils.join(synonyms, ", ");
        response.getOutputStream().print(responseString);
    }

    private static String getInputWordFromURL(String URL) {
        String[] tokenizedURL = URL.split("/");
        String word = tokenizedURL[tokenizedURL.length - 1];
        return word;
    }

    private RecentCache cache;
    private SynonymProvider provider;
}

    interface RecentCache {
        List<String> get(String word);
        void put(String word, List<String> synonyms);
    }

    interface SynonymProvider {
        List<String> getSynonyms(String word);
    }

    public class SynonymServletTest {

        @Mocked 
        RecentCache cache;

        @Mocked
        SynonymProvider provider;

        @Test
        public void should_always_look_into_cache_first() throws ServletException, IOException {
            //Mock
            new Expectations() {
                {
                    cache.get("reputation");
                    times = 1;
                }
            };

            SynonymServlet servlet = new SynonymServlet(cache, provider);
            servlet.doGet(getRequest("/synonyms/reputation"), new MockHttpServletResponse());
        }

        @Test
        public void should_return_from_cache_when_found() throws Exception, IOException {
            //Stub
            new Expectations() {
                {
                    cache.get("reputation");
                    result = new ArrayList<String>() {{
                        add("credit");
                        add("reputation");
                    }}; 
                }
            };

            MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
            SynonymServlet servlet = new SynonymServlet(cache, provider);

            servlet.doGet(getRequest("/synonyms/reputation"), response);

            assertThat(response.getContentAsString()).isEqualTo("credit, reputation");
        }

        @Test
        public void should_get_it_from_provider_when_not_found_in_cache() throws ServletException, IOException {
            //Stub
            new NonStrictExpectations() 
            {
                {
                    cache.get("reputation");
                    result = null;
                }
            };

            //Mock
            new Expectations() {
                {
                    provider.getSynonyms("reputation");
                    times = 1;
                }
            };

            SynonymServlet servlet = new SynonymServlet(cache, provider);
            servlet.doGet(getRequest("/synonyms/reputation"), new MockHttpServletResponse());
        }

        @Test
        public void should_return_the_same_as_provided_by_provider() throws ServletException, IOException {
            //Stub
            new NonStrictExpectations() {
                {
                    cache.get("reputation");
                    result = null;
                }
            };

            new Expectations() {
                {
                    provider.getSynonyms("reputation");
                    times = 1;
                    result = new ArrayList<String>() {{
                        add("credit");
                        add("reputation");
                    }}; 
                }
            };

            SynonymServlet servlet = new SynonymServlet(cache, provider);
            MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();

            servlet.doGet(getRequest("/synonyms/reputation"), response);

            assertThat(response.getContentAsString()).isEqualTo("credit, reputation");
        }

        @Test
        public void should_update_cache_when_not_in_cache() throws ServletException, IOException {
            //Stub
            new Expectations() {
                {
                    cache.get("reputation");
                    result = null;
                }
            };

            //Stub
            new Expectations() {
                {
                    provider.getSynonyms("reputation");
                    result = new ArrayList<String>() {{
                        add("credit");
                        add("reputation");
                    }}; 
                }
            };

            //Mock
            new Expectations() {
                {
                    cache.put("reputation", (List<String>) any);
                    times = 1;
                }
            };

            SynonymServlet servlet = new SynonymServlet(cache, provider);
            servlet.doGet(getRequest("/synonyms/reputation"), new MockHttpServletResponse());
        }

        private MockHttpServletRequest getRequest(String url) {
            return new MockHttpServletRequestBuilder()
                .withURL(url)
                .build();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's just a detail, but declaring the member variables at the end of the class is unusual and does not help for readability.

Answer (score 3):

Your tests looks good although I don't have any experience with JMockit (just Mockito and EasyMock) so I might miss some JMockit-specific issues. Here is a few notes about the code:

1. Instead of

   > ```
   > String[] tokenizedURL = URL.split("/");
   > String word = tokenizedURL[tokenizedURL.length - 1];
   > ```

   You could use [`StringUtils.substringAfterLast`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substringAfterLast%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). See also: [Simplest way to get last word in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24438432/843804)
2. I would consider creating a new class for the cache management logic, so you could test it without any servlet logic. I mean something like this:

   ```
   public class CachingSynonymProvider implements SynonymProvider {

       private final SynonymProvider synonymProvider;
       private final RecentCache recentCache;

       public CachingSynonymProvider(final SynonymProvider synonymProvider, 
               final RecentCache recentCache) {
           this.synonymProvider = checkNotNull(synonymProvider, "synonymProdiver cannot be null");
           this.recentCache = checkNotNull(recentCache, "recentCache cannot be null");
       }

       @Override
       public List<String> getSynonyms(final String word) {
           ...
       }

   }
   ```

   It might make the `RecentCache` unnecessary or you just could refactor/move its content to the `CachingSynonymProvider` class.
3. In `should_update_cache_when_not_in_cache()` there is the following line:

   > ```
   > cache.put("reputation", (List<String>) any);
   > ```

   I would be more strict here or verify it at the end of the test what's the value of the second parameter of `put`. If the code has a bug and always puts an empty list into the cache your second and subsequent `get` calls would give wrong results.
4. You could eliminate here a compiler warning:

   > ```
   > result = new ArrayList<String>() {{
   >     add("credit");
   >     add("reputation");
   > }};
   > ```

   and make it shorter with [Guava's `newArrayList`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#newArrayList%28E...%29):

   ```
   result = newArrayList("credit", "reputation");
   ```
5. I would consider extracting out common parts of unit tests to methods to remove duplication and express the purpose of the code. For example,

   > ```
   > //Stub
   > new Expectations() {
   >     {
   >         cache.get("reputation");
   >         result = null;
   >     }
   > };
   > ```

   could be in a method called `setEmptyCacheContentFor(String word)` or something similar.
6. I usually declare my `@Test` methods with a generic `throws Exception`. JUnit will catch all of the exceptions and it makes life easier when a tested method gets a new checked exception: you don't have to modify the signature of all of your tests.
7. Fields (`cache`, `provider`) should be at the beginning of the class, then comes the constructor, then the other methods. (According to the [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141855.html), 3.1.3 Class and Interface Declarations.)
8. Does it make sense to create a `SynonymServlet` with `null` `RecentCache` or `SynonymProvider`? Since it would throw an exception sooner or later I would check it and throw an `IllegalArgumentException` or `NullPointerException` from the constructor. Throwing an exception immediately helps debugging a lot since you get a stacktrace with the frames of the erroneous client, not just a `NullPointerException` later, maybe from another thread. (*Effective Java, Second Edition*, *Item 38: Check parameters for validity*; *The Pragmatic Programmer: From Journeyman to Master* by *Andrew Hunt* and *David Thomas*: *Dead Programs Tell No Lies*.)
9. The parameter name is uppercase here:

   > ```
   > private static String getInputWordFromURL(String URL) {
   > ```

   while in the test is lowercase which is not consistent:

   > ```
   > private MockHttpServletRequest getRequest(String url) {
   > ```

   I've found the lowercase one easier to read, I would use that.

   From *Effective Java, 2nd edition, Item 56: Adhere to generally accepted naming conventions*:

   > While uppercase may be more common, 
   >   a strong argument can made in favor of capitalizing only the first 
   >   letter: even if multiple acronyms occur back-to-back, you can still 
   >   tell where one word starts and the next word ends. 
   >   Which class name would you rather see, HTTPURL or HttpUrl?
10. Instead of returning `null` from `RecentCache.get` I'd consider using `Optional<List<String>>`. It makes explicit that it could return absent/empty value, so it's harder to miss the `null` check. [Java 8 introduced an Optional class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) but [there is one in Guava too](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained).

Comment: I am not able to understand the #2. What benefit we got by breaking the coupling between cache and servlet class? I am also not clear about the benefit of #10. Even if I use optional from Guava, the consumer of the cache still needs to make a check.

Comment: @AnandPatel: #2: [Easier to understand/maintain](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/232969/36726) and test in isolation (you need fewer mock objects), less complexity, [higher abstraction level](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A7076+abstraction+level). #10: Yes, he or she still need to do a check but it's much harder to forget it. It makes explicit that `get` might return nothing (which is less error-prone). (Read the *What's the point?* part of the linked Guava documentation too.)